# Who invented RAIL

Tags: interface, response-time

Since April 2015 I have been seeing a lot of references to the RAIL concept (Response Animation Idle Load) being made on blogs and in conferences as a way of evaluating the performance of user interfaces. I am not able to find the origin of this term. Who coined this?

URLs:

http://q42.com/blog/post/116938038438/it-was-a-smashing-conf

http://publishing-project.rivendellweb.net/web-content-optimization-rail-putting-the-user-first/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It came from Google

RAIL is a UI performance metrics framework created by the Chrome dev team. They use it to gain focus on the various aspects of responsiveness within the app itself and as a guideline to developers in the wild to improve the web app ecosystem.

A well articulated explanation was recently offered at the [Chrome Dev Summit](https://youtu.be/wO9GGY17NXY). As you noted in your comment, it has been spoken about throughout the year at other events such as the [Loop Conference](https://loopconf.io/talks/performance-guide-rail/) in the Spring.